# Umbraco, field="innerMacro", enable macro for insertion throw content editor

Tags: c#, .net, macros, umbraco

I have this in template:

```
<umbraco:Item field="innerMacro" runat="server"></umbraco:Item>
```

After creating content node from the template I want to insert macro there in content editor, but that macro is not in the list of available options. Tried to switch macros 'Use in editor' on and off, it doesn't take effect.

Please, help

Answer (score 0):

Check for the datatype. It should be `richtexteditor`.